# Why I cannot load and access image files with xampp 1.8.3-5 on mac?

Tags: php, html, macos, xampp

I am using xampp 1.8.3-5 mac-osx. I have problem on loading and accessing image files. When I directly access image from address bar like (localhost/myfile/img/img1.png), it give me result of "Access forbidden". 
I try to load image in  Still, it doesn't show out anything except the sign "question mark". I don't know why. Can somebody tell me the problem please?